# Setting an Embers.js property from within Handlebars.js

Tags: node.js, ember.js, pug, handlebars.js

I have a site that is using Node.js with Jade on the backend, and on the client-side I am using Handelbars.js with Embers.js.  I am passing a property into my .jade template for my flickr apiKey, so that I can keep all these keys in one server side json file.  I then want to set my Embers flickrPhotoSearchRequestModel's property in the html, so that it can use it to access the api.

I am trying to do

```
script(type='text/x-handlebars')
  {{Piccee.flickrPhotoSearchRequestModel.set('api_key', 1)}}
```

But, that does not seem to work.

FlickrController.js

```
Piccee.FlickrPhotoSearchRequestModel = Em.Object.extend({
api_key: "",
searchTerm: "",
page: 1,
url: function() {
    var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search";
    url += '&api_key=' + this.get("api_key");
    url += '&tags=' + this.get("searchTerm");
    url += '&text=' + this.get("searchTerm");
    url += '&page=' + this.get('page'); 
    url += '&sort=interestingness-desc&extras=url_sq%2C+url_t%2C+url_s%2C+url_q%2C+url_m%2C+url_n%2C+url_z%2C+url_c%2C+url_l%2C+url_o&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
    return url;
}.property('api_key', 'searchTerm', 'page'),    
});

Piccee.flickrPhotoSearchRequestModel = Piccee.FlickrPhotoSearchRequestModel.create({
api_key: "123",
searchTerm: "",
page: 1
```

});

In .js, that above set method would work just fine, it just won't work in the Handelebar's template.

Answer (score 0):

Ember does not execute what is in the brackets, so trying something like a `set` will not work.  Instead you should create a View and take in your data as parameters (ie "api_key").  Now I would normally recommend doing this via bindings so stuff could update/propagate but your data is generated in the HTML and only needs to be executed on once... So you might try something like this:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars'>
    {{#view SomeView api_key=1}}
        <a {{bindAttr href="piccee.url"}}>Some Pics</a>
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

Then:

```
SomeView = Em.View.extend({
    api_key: null,
    piccee: null,

    init: function(){
        this._super();
        this.set('piccee', Piccee.FlickrPhotoSearchRequestModel.create({ 
            api_key: this.get('api_key'); 
        }));
    }
});
```

If you are having trouble with this, let me know and I will create a fiddler.

All that being said, you could also register your own handlebars helper (though `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper`) which can take in parameters and draw a view.  It essentially makes a widget; I would only go down this path once you had the view working and you knew you wanted to use it over and over again.

**EDIT:** So, now we want bind that value instead of setting it initially.  You can reference `parentViews` in your paths which makes things like this kind of nice.

```
{{#view SomeHeaderView api_key=1}}
    ...
    stuff & things 
    ...

    {{#each myList}}
        {{#view SomeView}}
            ... link here ...
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

And inside that url (change the `api_key` to be `parentView.api_key`):

```
...
url: function() {
    var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search";
    url += '&api_key=' + this.get("parentView.api_key");
    url += '&tags=' + this.get("searchTerm");
    url += '&text=' + this.get("searchTerm");
    url += '&page=' + this.get('page'); 
    url += '&sort=interestingness-desc&extras=url_sq%2C+url_t%2C+url_s%2C+url_q%2C+url_m%2C+url_n%2C+url_z%2C+url_c%2C+url_l%2C+url_o&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
    return url;
    }.property('parentView.api_key', 'searchTerm', 'page'),    
...
```

I usually end up with a view because I find I want more then simple operations and it is [legit](http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_displaying-a-list-of-items).  I am still not 100% sure I follow, but I think this is the direction you are going.

Comment: Thanks, yea I have been a bit confused about how to implement the views.  I understand the models and controllers very well.  Say I have a page that in the header has an input text and a button to do the search, and then below it i have a div area that gets loaded with a bunch of image divs from the flickr response.  Would I create a HeaderView and an ImageView?  Because right now I am simply doing this {{#each Piccee.flickrController}}
                    <img {{bindAttr src="url_s"}} />                
                {{/each}} in my html page to show them

Comment: One other caveat, the api_key is coming in as a Jade variable, so {{#view Piccee.FlickrHeaderView api_key=!{flickrApiKey}}} does not work.  I am tring to figure that one out as well.

Comment: And I do not know of a solution for your jade/handlebars problem but I am sure other people have solved that at some point.

Comment: See the "EDIT" above for your answer about `views` in `each`.

Comment: So I see you are saying make it this {{#each myList}} {{#view SomeView}} ... link here ... {{/view}} {{/each}} instead of  {{#each Piccee.flickrController}} <img {{bindAttr src="url_s"}} /> {{/each}} so myList would be a property on the view that would get it's data from the flickrController.  I also have a funciton on flickrController which will get the next set of images <button {{action "nextFlickrPhotos" target="Piccee.flickrController"}}>Next</button>, would I add a nextFlickrPhotos function to my SomeHeaderView that would then just in turn call the flickrController.

Comment: (Thanks by the way, this view part was the very last section I needed to figure out, and this is helping tremendously.)

Comment: Yes, I believe a ember purest would agree with making the action target to the view and the view fire off the controller action (vc part of mvc).